# Making this div responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Could someone please explain me how I can make this div responsive using media queries? It's practically a 200px high div with sponsor logos on it. I want it to be responsive. Currently the logo's are displayed horizontally but for example, they should be stacking one on top of the other on the mobile version.

```
    <div id="sponsors">
      <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
        <div class="sponsors">
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-centered" style="margin-top: 40px; ">
                    <img src="img/bridgestone.png" class="hvr-pulse" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 20px;";>
                </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-centered" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                    <img src="img/sparco1.png" class="hvr-pulse" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 20px;">
                </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-centered" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <img src="img/redbull.png" class="hvr-pulse" style=" width: 300px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

#sponsors {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:  black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: So you want the black box wrapping them to expand it's height accordingly in mobile view? Also, judging by your class names, I reckon you are using Bootstrap?

Comment: It's good practice to add code examples to questions using jsfiddle or something similar, and let us know what you've tried so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Andrew, that's exactly what I want. And yes, I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: @Luke, haven't tried anything yet regarding the responsive div/wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `sponsors` height to `min-height` like this:

```
#sponsors {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/97/ [Dummy images use]

---

P.s. as you might have noticed in the fiddle, the inline margins are removed because you can achieve what you want by adding some `padding` to the box wrapping the images.

Comment: Okay, that seems to work now that I shrink the browser. But when on normal monitor-width view, the div became huge ( height of about 700px; )

Comment: Glad I could help John :) Do mark this as the right answer if it helped in solving your issue.

Comment: Done. Thank you, once again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a meta tag to identify the width and media queries to perform an action when the width is different. It would also be very helpful to add percentage onto your css elements rather than pixels.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width:761px){
    div.sponsers{
        background-color:black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

A great framework to use since you're just starting out with responsive design would be using Bootstrap, it's easily customised to fit the needs of your project.

There is one good website as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries